# DateEdit DevExpress

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Работаю с `DateEdit` (контрол *DevExpress*). Хочу сделать так, чтобы при запуске программы поле `Text` было заполнено и редактирование контрола было запрещено.

```
<dxe:DateEdit DateTime="{Binding FromDate}" Text="Od" Height="23" Width="161" Margin="3" EditValue="Od" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите свойство `IsReadOnly = "True"`. Поле `Text` у вас уже устанавливается.